# How to avoid throttling on sharepoint with decorating useragent in csom/odata

Tags: sharepoint, csom

For Azure Automation function I have tried to use the UserAgent decoration for CSOM requests on sharepoint to avoid throttling like described in the following Article from MS -> [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#how-to-decorate-your-http-traffic-to-avoid-throttling).

The example code below in C# shows the decoration of the user agent. I will use it later with PowerShell. This works also with an test decoration string.

what I can't find is how to register an app at sharepoint and what I need for it. In this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/register-sharepoint-add-ins) is a general description of how to register an app. But for the decoration string, as described in the first MS article, we need "AppID and AppTitle" which doesn't meets the requirements of the decoration string types ->

1. ISV Application  – ISV|CompanyName|AppName/Version
2. Enterprise Application  – NONISV|CompanyName|AppName/Version

Is the AppName equal to the Title in the App registration? For what I need ClientId, Client Secret and the two URLs by register the App if I can not use it in the useragent decoration string?

```
// Get access to source site
    using (var ctx = new ClientContext("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/team"))
    {
        //Provide account and pwd for connecting to SharePoint Online
        var passWord = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("contoso@contoso.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);

        // Add our User Agent information
        ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += delegate (object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.UserAgent = "NONISV|Contoso|GovernanceCheck/1.0";
        };

        // Normal CSOM Call with custom User-Agent information
        Web site = ctx.Web;
        ctx.Load(site);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

Comment: This is a good question, and yes the documentation is not clear. From what I can gather, AppName is arbitrary - it matters more _that_ you have the decoration than specifically what it says. In any case the more important aspect is to implement incremental back off in response to 429s, regardless of decoration, and to carefully structure your logic to limit the number of calls your code makes, and maximise what you’re retrieving or doing in each call.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The issue what I have with the documentation is that there is a way described how to avoid throtteling but the details are missing. I hope someone know how to use it.

Comment: In our software, we put our application's name and build version in the user agent string without registering the app on MS site. So far, we haven't had any problem with throttle.

Comment: have you ever tested how many parallel requests you can start with one account? Is there a difference? @JackLe

Comment: @theface I have tested doing something else (updating multiple `ListItem` objects) and the most parallel requests was 5.

Comment: it is between 5 and 8

Comment: This is exactly the question I was about to ask and want to know the answer for :)